# Is it proper style to have blank lines tabbed properly?

Tags: java, git, styles, whitespace, tabbing

In Java, let's say I had two method declarations in a class:

```
class MyClass {
    public void myMethod() {
        // Some code
    }

    public void myOtherMethod() {
        // Some more code
    }
}
```

In between my methods, I can choose to either have a completely blank line, or have a space characters "properly" tabbing the line. I've noticed that prior to committing, my git diffs that sometimes otherwise unchanged files contain changes that are purely whitespace (either adding or erasing the above mentioned whitespace). This just got me thinking:

Are there any style guidelines as to whether either is correct?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of and syntactically it's meaningless.

Comment: Not sure how relevant this is, but I make sure I don't use tab _characters_ (`\t`) in sources.  They cause problems if you cut-and-paste the code and try to include it somewhere else, such as in a document or a discussion group post (they cause _big_ formatting problems when people use them in StackOverflow questions).  If you try to change the indentation of source with tab characters, things won't line up properly depending on how a particular text editor handles it.

Comment: Quite true, @ajb. I also very much avoid using \t in any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no *official* style guidelines for what makes up your whitespace

That being said... I do tend to remove unnecessary tabs/spaces - just because that's my preference. Though, I wouldn't ever take the time to tell someone else to do the same.. (*Well, okay - except this one time*)

Comment: True, you should always use your project's guidelines before any other.

Answer (score 1):

Most people lean towards removing them. They take up space unnecessarily (think of the bytes you could save!) and `git diff --check` is configured by default to flag leading whitespace on otherwise empty lines.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know about `git diff --check`